# How to diagnose slow startup time in Cloud Run containers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, google-cloud-run

I am running some services with Google Cloud Run. While performance has been satisfactory, there's a recurrent issue with extremely slow startup time, which leads to occasionally dropped requests when new containers can't spin up in time.

Currently, with first gen execution environments and startup CPU boost enabled, Google's dashboard reports around 18 to 50 seconds of startup time. Image is based on `ruby:3.0.2`, and it runs a Ruby on Rails 6 application. In a development environment, startup (timed from `run` to container accepting requests) never seems to take more than 5 seconds.

I want to know what tools are available to diagnose this issue, and if there are any obvious pitfalls with my specific case that I might be missing.

I've tried playing around with the service's configuration options, to no avail. The biggest suspect is a startup bash script that handles migrations on the first boot, and asset compiling on development. However, I've tried building with an empty script, and the problem persists. I also think the container images might be too large (around 700Mb), but I haven't gotten around to slimming then down nor found evidence that this is the problem.

Comment: The container image is not the issue. In addition, you have to compare the exact same things. CPU speed on the cloud are about 2.4Ghz, your local environment is about 4 or 5 Ghz. CPU on Cloud Run is max 8 CPUs, on your computer, it could be 8, 12, 16 or more! 18s on Cloud Run compare to 5 locally is great! 50s is strange, but can happen! CPU generation, availability, region, many thing can impact the performances.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/trace)? It can help you debug what may be slowing down the container startup time.

Comment: If I remember well Cloud Run docs say explicitly to do not perform migrations at start time (they have to be managed separately).

Comment: From the docs: "...With Cloud Run jobs, we can now check off that last factor, as Cloud Run now has a way to run admin processes! You can use this pattern for things such as applying one-off commands, or more complex tasks like running database schema migrations for your deployments that rely on web frameworks (such as in Django, Rails, or Laravel). This article will focus on the database schema migration use case..."

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/running-database-migrations-cloud-run-jobs

Comment: Also, is your docker image including only production dependencies? That might have a huge effect on startup time.